# How to deal with outlier in the experiment

Tags: experiment-design

My question is related to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23556/should-i-repeat-experiment-affected-by-external-factors-until-achieving-consiste). I'm working on an experiment involving transferring data between different locations all over the world via the Internet. As the Internet can be busy, sometimes it takes longer to transfer the same amount of data than the other times. The difference can be significant, e.g. for the 1mb of data, it normally takes 2 seconds to transfer, but occasionally (around 1 out of 20 times), it can take up to 20 seconds or more.

I am comparing different setups for the same problem. For each one, I perform multiple times and get the average result, i.e. time to solve the problem. However, as outlier can happen at one setup but not on another, my comparison is affected.

So, at the moment, for each setup, I perform M times but only get the average of N of the smallest results (N < M). I also plan to state and justify my method in the paper as well.

So, my question is whether my method is acceptable and if it makes my paper less reliable. I'm also interested in how experimental outlier is handled in general. I'm working in CS but answers from other fields are welcome.

Comment: What you have done seems related to a “trimmed mean” (but not exactly the same). It's OK but it might be easier to justify if you would remove observations at both ends (e.g. remove the 5% smallest and 5% largest times).

Answer (score 4):

Think of this from the position of a reader who wants to use your research to deside between these setups. She will want to know that one setup is more likely to occationally need substantial longer times even if a "typical" session will be faster. I would report say the 50th percentile (median) and the 95th percentile (your 1 in 20 outlier). That way you give a fair account of both the typical time it takes to solve a problem and what to expect in a "bad run".